How to remove title bar from window but keep minimize/maximize animations?
When clicking on a window's icon on the Taskbar, it will minimize or restore with standard animations, but when creating the window with this code:
WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(wc), CS_CLASSDC, WndProc, 0L, 0L, hInstance, LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1)), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, window::class_name, nullptr };
::RegisterClassEx(&wc);
g_hWnd = ::CreateWindowExA(0, wc.lpszClassName, window::window_name, WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU, x, y, window::g_Width, window::g_Height, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, nullptr);

It removes the title bar, but also removes the animations. The window  is still able to minimize and restore, but without animations.
I tried several styles, but still it requires either the title bar or no animations.

You may Custom Window Frame Using DWM.

The documentation says that you can't use WS_SYSMENU (and by extension, WS_MINIMIZEBOX or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX) without using WS_CAPTION.

Create a standard window as you would do usually. Process the message WM_NCCALCSIZE by returning zero or one (See the doc. I don't remember exactly). This will remove the standard frame, keeping all the standard behaviour.
